# i just display all files from specific folder..now how can match file names and then display in java

Tags: java

```
   package my;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class readfile {

    File root = new File("C:\\hpcl");
    String filename[] = {};
    FilenameFilter beginwith = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.startsWith("M") && name.endsWith(".TXT"));
        }
    };
 File root1 = new File("C:\\hpcl1");
  FilenameFilter beginwithR = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.startsWith("R") && name.endsWith(".TXT"));
        }
    };
    public void getDataM() {

        File[] files = root.listFiles(beginwith);
        int i = 0;
        String f1="";
        String f2[]={};
        System.out.println("Mfile");
        for (File f : files) {

              System.out.println(f.getName());



         }

    }
  public void getDataR() {

        File[] files = root1.listFiles(beginwithR);
        int i = 0;
        String f1="";
        String f2[]={};
        System.out.println("Mfile");
        for (File f : files) {

               System.out.println(f.getName());


         }
            }
public void matchfile()
    {


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        my.readfile rl = new my.readfile();

        rl.getDataM();
        rl.getDataR();
           //System.out.print(rl.getData());



}
}
```

this program show....getdataM method displays all startwith M files from specific folder and getDataR() displays R files....
now i want to change initial char of M file to R and then check further name is same or not..if it is same then shows that R files only....
so help me foe java program....this program metheds have to display in jsp page...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a homework so I will not give you a complete answer but some remarks or suggestions:

- The name of your class is not correct: it should begin wit an upper-case letter and the first letter of each part should be also in upper case.
- Why don't you create a a class implementing FileFilter where you can pass the patter of the file to search as a parameter? you do the same with your getData*X* methods.
- Same remark about the directory to scan. It should obviously be a parameter.
- You code displays filename in a console. There are many solution to do what you intend to: your methods getData*X* can return a String (a HTML list for example) you can display in JSP, they can return a a collection(why not use directly file filters in JSP...) and last butnot least you can define new tag. Take a look at JSTL
- It should be a good ideau to chek in your list if the element is a file or a directory.
- You should also make your code bulletproof. There are some Try {...} catch{...} missing

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand your question.
do you want to compare every character of the filename?

eg:
 mobert.txt
 richard.txt

in the first step mobert becomes robert and after that u want to compare o and i, b and c ?!

if u just want to compare the names u can always use f1.getName().equals(f2.getName());

for each char it would be:

```
for (i=0; i<f1.getName().length+1; i++){
String compare1= f1.getName().subString(i,i+1);
String compare2= f2.getName().subString(i,i+1);
if(compare1.equals(compare2){
 return true;
else{
 return false;
    }
}
```

cheers